# Longest lines of file descending

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge, file

This is a challenge question from [codeeval.com](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/2/):

> Write a program which reads a file and prints to stdout the specified
>   number of the longest lines that are sorted based on their length in
>   descending order. Input sample:
>
> Your program should accept a path to a file as its first argument. The
>   file contains multiple lines. The first line indicates the number of
>   lines you should output, the other lines are of different length and
>   are presented randomly. You may assume that the input file is
>   formatted correctly and the number in the first line is a valid
>   positive integer.
>
> **For Example:**
>
> ```
> 2 
> Hello World
> CodeEval 
> Quick Fox
> A
> San Francisco
> ```
>
> **Output sample:**
>
> Print out the longest lines limited by specified number and sorted by
>   their length in descending order.
>
> **For example:**
>
> ```
> San Francisco 
> Hello World
> ```

I think my code is pretty readable.

```
lines = IO
  .readlines(ARGV.first)

puts lines
  .drop(1)
  .sort_by(&:length)
  .last(lines.first.to_i)
  .reverse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a file named on the command line is a common task.  I suggest making use of the `ARGF` to accomplish that.

Not all lines of the input are to be treated uniformly.  Since the first line is to be treated differently, I suggest defining `lines` to exclude it.

```
top_n, *lines = ARGF.to_a
puts lines.sort_by(&:length).last(top_n.to_i).reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sort_by` + `last` implementation is simple enough and looks quite good. I know it's probably not the case but, just for fun, let's imagine you had a humongous file to process; it wouldn't have a terribly nice space complexity (O(n)). In this case, I'd use a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Equivalence_of_priority_queues_and_sorting_algorithms) (let's say with logarithmic time of insertions/removals):

```
lines = open(ARGV.first).lines
heap_size = lines.first.to_i
sorted_queue = lines.reduce(PriorityQueue.new) do |queue, line|
  queue.add(line.size, line).limit(heap_size)
end
sorted_queue.values.each { |line| puts(line) }
```

The final performance would be O(n * log K) time, and constant space K (the size of the heap). The implementation of `PriorityQueue` is left as an exercise for the reader ;)